# Why is my code working in proteus but not when burned into chip?

Tags: avr, atmega, infrared, proteus, atmel-studio

I am using atmel chip and I have a problem with the code, I guess. Trying to make automatic light system. I am working with two IR sensors that should detect a person entering and leaving the room. I have connected them to PC0 and PC1. The LED is connected to PB0 and should be ON when someone enters the room, and OFF when room is empty. When I tried it in proteus it worked fine, but now the chip doesn't give the same results. LED goes ON when sensors detect the person, but then wont go off whatever I do.

This is my code:

```
void LED( uint8_t x )
{
    if ( x == 0 ) //if no persons in the room
    {
        PORTB &= ~( 1<<0 ); // LED OFF 
    }
    else
    {
        PORTB |= ( 1<<0 ); // LED ON
    }
}

int main( void )  
{
    DDRB = 0xFF; // LED
    DDRC = 0x00; // IR sensors
    uint8_t count = 0;
 
    while (1)
    {
        if ( PINC & ( 1<<0 ) ) //check if first sensor detected
        { 
            // entrance
            while ( ! ( PINC & ( 1<<1 ) ) ); // waits for the second to detect
            while ( PINC & ( 1<<1 ) ); // second sensor stops detecting 
            ++count; 
        }
        else if ( PINC & ( 1<<1 ) ) // second sensor detects first
        {
            // exit
            while ( ! ( PINC & ( 1<<0 ) ) );  
            while ( PINC & ( 1<<0 ) ); 
            --count;
        }

        LED( count );
    }
}
```

The compiler does not report an error.
Please keep in mind I am a student, beginner at this field, any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: To start with, a little more information about how this sensor setup works would be useful. Otherwise, a good place to start debugging would be to add some other outputs to see what is actually being triggered in your code. Are you getting stuck in a while loop somewhere? Is your count variable incrementing multiple times, and thus never coming down to 0? Once you have more information on where the actual behavior differs from expected, finding the issue should be easier.

Comment: I would start by reading one input turning the LED on/off. If that's not working, nothing else will. Maybe you have a configuration issue or maybe there is no clock present.

Comment: Be aware that the microcontroller is sampling your inputs maybe a million times per second. You might be lucky to see the led flash. Put some delays in the code to slow it down.